# Source for taking an oath on beard and payos

Tags: nedarim-shevuot, payot-sideburns, beard

I remember seeing in a sefer that when Jews would take an oath they would take one on their beard and payos, this showed how much they valued the mitzvah of beard and payos.

Does anyone know where this can be found?

Comment: This is probably connected to Rashi on [Genesis 24:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.24.2.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Comment: It appears in Mendele Moychr Sforim's די קליאטשע, fwiw. Or at least in [this Hebrew translation thereof](https://benyehuda.org/mos/susati_no_nikkud.html).

Answer (score 7):

I found the source I was looking for ,it is from the Chofetz Chaim in his Kuntres Tiferes Adam (on the issur of shaving ). He writes that he remembers that when a Jew took a vow he would do so with his beard and payos.

[image]